# asp.net core 2.0 web app fails to connect to db2 on System i

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ibm-midrange, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to develop a web app to connect to db2 on i series and as part of that I have to query a small file and then display it's some contents in a view.

I'm new to asp.net, but have connected to the same system i server using iDB2Connection, ODBC and OleDb while developing for windows desktop.

Issue from my web app is as follows :

DB2Exception: ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected: "xxx.xxx.xx.xx". Communication function detecting the error: "connect". Protocol specific error code(s): "10060", "*", "*". SQLSTATE=08001.

The code snippet which fails :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xx;Database=test;UID=xxx;
    pwd=xxxx;
    con.Open(); // fails here

    DB2Command com = new DB2Command("select * from lib.file", con);

    ...
```

I have tried adding Connection reset = false, Adding TCP keepalive to registry,
disabling antivirus/firewall to no avail, reading up on Connection Time-out as the reason for the 10060 SQL Code 30081N.

Please help me fix this, I've been breaking my head over this for long.

Comment: I've missed some dbl quotes in connection string when pasting here and editing, but connection string is fine in the app, when I pass the system name, it resolves to the correct IP address in the error.

Comment: I have the IBM.Data.DB2.Core from NuGet and path is set as mentioned in the FAQ

Comment: IBM i is a bit different as the database is integrated with the OS. So when you connect, you generally don't need a database name. In fact, that might be what is holding you up.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, thanks, but I ve tried that as well, if I do not give the database, then I get an invalid argument exception when setting the connection string.

Comment: On an IBM i command line, type `WRKRDBDIRE` then find the line for `*LOCAL`. Use the value in the Entry column for Database. If that doesn't work, you can try using the data library name for database, but that would normally need to be the default schema.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, still doesn't work, same error.

Comment: however, I tried to connect using the same 'old' iDB2Connection from the VS's default template for asp.net MVC 5.0 web app. It works as expected. Maybe the issue is either with .net Core 2.0 or the IBM package in NuGet...?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: No, couldn't fix it and used .net instead of .net core, was easy as I was just starting to build out the app

Comment: @vidhyasome Did you fix it? I am really confused about the port number. Before I was using the .net framework and I do not need a port number in a connection string. But now I am using the IBM DB2 Core, it requires port number.

Comment: Sorry, I couldnt fix it and ended up using .net instead of .net core

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the port number in the connection string (in my case was 446):

`Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:446;Database=test;UID=xxx;pwd=xxxx;`